# Converting Object[] to List<Object> in this one-liner function in Java

Tags: java

still very new to Java, my apologies if this has appeared before.

Basically here is the original code

```
public static MarketType[] convert(final String[] values) {
        return ofNullable(values).map(v -> Stream.of(values))
                .orElse(Stream.empty())
                .map(v -> getMarketType(v))
                .toArray(MarketType[]::new);
}
```

Since other functions changed, I really need the return type to be `List<MarketType>` instead of `MarketType[]`, but is there any way that can achieve this with the minimal amount of modification for the original code?
I have been trying to put different things in the `toArray` function but nothing really worked.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Instead of this `toArray(MarketType[]::new);` use `collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: And also `map(this::getMarketType)`.